# Staying login problem about CallbackURL after payment

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

my view is like :

```
def get_user_pending_order(request):
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    order = Order.objects.filter(owner=user_profile, is_ordered=False)
    if order.exists():
        return order[0]
    return 0

MERCHANT = 'xxx...xxx'
ZP_API_REQUEST = "https://api.zarinpal.com/pg/v4/payment/request.json"
ZP_API_VERIFY = "https://api.zarinpal.com/pg/v4/payment/verify.json"
ZP_API_STARTPAY = "https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/StartPay/{authority}"
amount = ''
description = "text"  # Required
email = 'example@email.com'  # Optional
mobile = '09999999999'  # Optional
# Important: need to edit for realy server.
CallbackURL = 'https://example.com/payment/verify/'


def send_request(request):
    print(get_user_pending_order(request).owner.phone_number)
    req_data = {
        "merchant_id": MERCHANT,
        "amount": int(get_user_pending_order(request).get_total()),
        "callback_url": CallbackURL,
        "description": description,
        "metadata": {"mobile": mobile,
            "email": email}
    }
    req_header = {"accept": "application/json",
                  "content-type": "application/json'"}
    req = requests.post(url=ZP_API_REQUEST, data=json.dumps(
        req_data), headers=req_header)
    authority = req.json()['data']['authority']
    if len(req.json()['errors']) == 0:
        return redirect(ZP_API_STARTPAY.format(authority=authority))
    else:
        e_code = req.json()['errors']['code']
        e_message = req.json()['errors']['message']
        return HttpResponse(f"Error code: {e_code}, Error Message: {e_message}")


def verify(request):
    t_status = request.GET.get('Status')
    t_authority = request.GET['Authority']
    if request.GET.get('Status') == 'OK':
        req_header = {"accept": "application/json",
                      "content-type": "application/json'"}
        req_data = {
            "merchant_id": MERCHANT,
            "amount": int(get_user_pending_order(request).get_total()),
            "authority": t_authority
        }
        req = requests.post(url=ZP_API_VERIFY, data=json.dumps(req_data), headers=req_header)
        if len(req.json()['errors']) == 0:
            t_status = req.json()['data']['code']
            if t_status == 100:
                user = request.user
                order_to_purchase = get_user_pending_order(request)
                order_to_purchase.is_ordered = True
                order_to_purchase.date_ordered=datetime.datetime.now()
                order_to_purchase.created_on_time=datetime.datetime.now()
                order_to_purchase.save()
                order_items = order_to_purchase.items.all()
                for order_item in order_items:
                    order_item.product.quantity = order_item.product.quantity - 1
                    order_item.product.save()
                order_items.update(is_ordered=True, date_ordered=datetime.datetime.now())
                subject = 'successful'
                c = {
                "refid":str(req.json()['data']['ref_id']),
                "ref_code":order_to_purchase.ref_code,
                "owner":order_to_purchase.owner,
                }
                email_template_name = "pay/after_pay_confirm_email.html"
                email_html = render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
                email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                send_mail(subject, email_html, email_from, [user.email], html_message=email_html)
                ctx = {'message_good':'good'}
                return render(request, 'pay/verify.html', ctx)
            elif t_status == 101:
                ...
            else:
                ....
        else:
            ...
    else:
        ...
```

At first about user, is logged. and about `send_request` function it work totally fine...so it pass user into Payment gateway and after successful payment it come back to `verify` function by `CallbackURL`. to show success page and do `order_to_purchase.is_ordered = True` ...
for me with my pc, phone, other android phones, ios, windows, linux. and about browsers like chrome Firefox it work correctly and everything is fine.
but some clients tell me they face to `'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable` after successful payment and when they back to verify. its kinda like that they logged out by pushing request to payment gateway.
also i made purchase by that account exactly same way and i didn't face to that error. it show is that phone or browser problem that half of my clients faced to that. i have no idea what should i do!!!

Comment: The case might be that your client was never logged in. You should really protect your views that require your users to be authenticated using the [login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) or the [LoginRequired mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I just added these decorators... but i tried my self even it was completely logged. but only some clients that i controlled their behaviors